# use .net webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, gridview

I have created a webservice in .net and want to access this webservice in andriod how to do that. Please help. I also need to bind the data returned by webservice to grid. Webservice will be returning a table of rows.

Answer (score 0):

> Useing **SAX parser** you can do this ::  i wrote one example here which help to you.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example
http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/sample-saxparser-in-android.html
http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/mobile/blog-detail/parsing_xml_on_android/
http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/parsing-xml-using-sax-parser-in-android-t1494.html
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-app-part-3-parsing-xml.html

> ***This all link are ready to help that how SAX parser are working.***

Comment: actually i am new to android development. i am trying to use org.ksoap2 but its not diplaying ksoap2 there. what do i need to do for that. do i need to add any library or so for that

Comment: For SOAP calls I would write my own envelope and then use one of the above examples to parse the response.

Comment: David i not able to import org.ksoap2. itz not diplaying it when i try to import it wt do i need to do.